# If doc values are used for a field in elasticsearch, is storing that field redundant?

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

As I understand it, storing a field in elasticsearch serves two purposes:

1. The field can be retrieved directly from disk without parsing `_source`. This would happen when using a fields query, for example.
2. If `_source` is disabled, the stored fields compose the document that is returned.

However, storing a field takes additional disk space and there are reasons to otherwise prefer to keep `_source` enabled in elasticsearch, so it's probably only worthwhile for larger documents.

Similarly, doc values stores fields that you can lookup by document. It seems that these fields are clustered on disk by field instead of by document, which makes it more efficient to retrieve a lot of the same field from different documents (sorting, aggregations, etc). This is done instead of caching all stored fields in memory for those operations.

My question is... if you have doc values, is there still a valid use-case for storing fields, and if so, what is it?

Ultimately, I'm trying to determine the correct mapping for fields where doc_values seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if elasticsearch will retrieve a field value for you if the field is not stored but it has docValues enabled for it. All i can tell you is that while it is customary for docValues to represent fields stored in a columnar manner (which as you pointed out , makes it easier for bulk retrieval needed for sorting or even function queries), lucene treats docValues as separate fields themselves.

So while in elasticsearch you enable docvalues on field `foo` and end up with the same data duplicated,underneath lucene will create a `docValues` field for each document and copy the data from the `foo` field to it. So in effect there is no guarantee at the lucene level that the data is duplicated, but there is one at the elasticsearch level.

To cut a long story short, this functionality you inquire about could be implemented (if it's not already)

Comment: Thanks for some clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but might help someone in the future.

#### doc values

[doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/doc-values.html) are indexed in a column-oriented fashion, and used to improve the performance of sorting, aggregation and script accessing. You can get the doc values by specifying [docvalue_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-docvalue-fields.html#search-request-docvalue-fields) in the query.

For those fields that support this feature, `doc_values` are enabled by default. However, analyzed string fields don't support `doc_values`. So if the field is of type *text*, you cannot get the doc value of this field.

#### store

[store](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/mapping-store.html) parameter is used to store the field value. So that we can avoid parsing *_source* to get the field value by specifying [stored_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-stored-fields.html) in the query. AFAIK, you can store fields of any type.

However, this feature costs extra disk space, so it's disabled by default. If *_source* is not a huge doc, normally you don't need to enable this feature.

#### fielddata

[fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/fielddata.html) is used for fields of text type. As I mentioned above, text field doesn't support doc values. Instead, when you want to get the field value (by specifying [docvalue_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-docvalue-fields.html#search-request-docvalue-fields) in the query), or do aggregation  on text field, ElasticSearch will load the inverted index from disk, inverting the term-doc relation, and cache the result in memory. So that we can get the field value.

However, this is not a cheap operation and might cost lots of memory. So this feature is disabled by default. And you should use it with caution!!!

> My question is... if you have doc values, is there still a valid use-case for storing fields, and if so, what is it?

YES. If *_source* is disabled, and you still want to get the value of a text field, you need to store it. Since *fielddata* might be a bad idea.